# Using python list to read in pandas CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in 12 separate CSV files and would like to use a for loop to do it. For some reason the code doesn't seem to be working:

```
files = ['Jan2016', 'Feb2016', 'Mar2016', 'Apr2016', 'May2016', 'Jun2016', 'Jul2016', 'Aug2016', 'Sep2016', 'Oct2016', 'Nov2016', 'Dec2016']

for file in files: 
    file = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Toshiba/PrescriptionData/Results2/" + i + ".csv")

print(Jan2016)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-906109eb8ce9> in <module>()
      4     file = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Toshiba/PrescriptionData/Results2/" + i + ".csv")
      5 
----> 6 print(Jan2016)

NameError: name 'Jan2016' is not defined
```

However, when I enter print(file) the code compiles and prints the data from the Dec2016 CSV file (i.e the final value in my 'files' list). Any ideas on why this for loop is not working?

Comment: Vishal you learnt about variables right? String can't be a variable. I suggest you to read more about  loops and variables.

Comment: Thank you, so is there any way I can use the values in the list as variable names?

Comment: the second answer in the linked question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `dict comprehension` for dictionary of DataFrames:

```
path = "/Volumes/Toshiba/PrescriptionData/Results2/"
dfs = {file : pd.read_csv(path + file + ".csv") for file in files}
```

What is same as:

```
dfs = {}
path = "/Volumes/Toshiba/PrescriptionData/Results2/"
for file in files: 
    dfs[file] = pd.read_csv(path + file + ".csv")
```

And then select in `dictionary` by keys:

```
print (dfs['Jan2016'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, unfortunately it still gives me the same problem

Comment: @Vishal tell me `"one" = 100` does this make sense. This is what is happening in your loop.

Comment: @Vishal - Can you explain more? What does not work?

Comment: @jezrael hes trying to create variables using for loop.

Comment: @Dark - yes that makes sense to me, what I'm trying to do is one=100, which according to me should work?

Comment: @jezrael apologies, I didn't see the code you put below the first 2 lines. I will try that, however I'm wondering whether by using a dictionary to store the data, I can use pandas functions like dataframe concatenation, which is what I would like to do with the 12 data frames

Comment: Dude `"one"` is different than `one`. For loop doesn't serve you fresh variables instead they serve the strings present in the list. Tell me the language you know complete basics of I will explain with the help of that. Things in programming language wont work according to one's wish it works according to fundamental principle.

Comment: @Vishal - each value in dict is normal `DataFrame`, so is possible use `df = pd.concat(dfs)` as next step

Comment: @jezrael Thank you! that works perfectly